# AjaxCallBack was not called, windows phone phonegap

Tags: angularjs, wcf, cordova

I am trying to connect WCF RESTful C# API to phonegap application using angularjs. My html working perfect in Web but no in my windows phone.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div data-ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
            First Name: {{FirstName}}
            Last Name: {{LastName}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        window.jsoncallback = function (json) {
            debugger;

            if (!json.Error) {

                alert("run callback");
                //alert("success");
            }
            else {

                alert(json.Message);
            }
        }
        
        myApp.controller('ProfileCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {

            function LoadProfile() {

                debugger;

                var call_url = 'http://localhost:53834/LoginService.svc/UserProfile/1';


                //For jsonp calling
                //alert("Running Jsonp");
                //$http.jsonp(call_url).success(function (data) {
                //    debugger;
                //});
                

                alert("Running Ajax");
                $.ajax({
                    url: call_url,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "jsonp",  // from the server
                    crossDomain: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // to the server
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsoncallback',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                        $scope.FirstName = data.FirstName;
                        $scope.LastName = data.LastName;
                        $scope.$apply();
                    },
                }).done(function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(data);

                }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(xhr.status + " " + status + " " + error);
                });
            };

            LoadProfile();
        }]);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my html code,

Service code is

```
public Stream UserProfile(string profileID)
    {
        TestDBEntities db = new TestDBEntities();

        int _ProfileID = Convert.ToInt32(profileID);
        tblProfile objtblProfile = db.tblProfiles.Find(_ProfileID);

        string jsCode;

        JavaScriptSerializer returnList = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string output = returnList.Serialize(objtblProfile);

        if (objtblProfile != null)
            jsCode = "jsoncallback" + "(" + output + ");";
        else
            jsCode = null;

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/javascript";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsCode));


    }
```

I have done all things but not working in my windows phone it is giving an error

> 200 parserror: jsoncallback was not called

but it is working perfect in Web normally.

Comment: You better look into [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) rather than using `$.ajax`!

Comment: I have use this also it also have same problem.
alert("Running Jsonp");
                $http.jsonp(call_url).success(function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    alert("success");
                            $scope.FirstName = data.FirstName;
                            $scope.LastName = data.LastName;
                            $scope.$apply();
                }).error(function(data){
                });

Comment: It is not calling success method also in web or windowsphone too

Answer (score 0):

The way I made an AJAX request in my application is as below. Take a look and see if this works out for you:

```
app.ajaxCall = function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', <URL>, false);
        //Content-Type can be based on the content you are sending
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        var params = <define param string here>;
        xhr.send(params);

        var isError = false;
        try {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                <logic>
            }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cross domain issue is coming in this because my service is on another server that's why i have to use jsonp this code doesn't work for me.

Comment: For Cross Domain requests you can implement CORSFilter in your API.

Comment: how to do that i am using WCF service in c#